# reactjs semantic-ui how to correctly modify a JSX tag conditionally

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have a tag that I want to define conditionally

```
<Table.Cell positive>{item}</Table.Cell>
```

Then, what's the correct way of doing it?
What I've done is substituting it with a function

```
{this.callme(item)}
```

and the function then returns this

```
callme = (item) => {
  let res;
  if (item && item > 3)
    res = <Table.Cell positive>{item}</Table.Cell>
  else if (item && item < -3)
    res = <Table.Cell negative>{item}</Table.Cell>
  else if (item)
    res = <Table.Cell>{item}</Table.Cell>
  else
    res = <Table.Cell>..</Table.Cell>
  return res;
```

But this is verbose. Then I've tried to modify things *inside* the tag but this is not allowed

```
<Table.Cell {mystate}>{item}</Table.Cell>
```

and then there the question. How can I modify a tag itself? How is it supposed to be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a slight adjustment to your approach that returns the component directly, rather than assign and return via `res`:

```
callme = (item) => {

  if (item && item > 3)
    return (<Table.Cell positive>{item}</Table.Cell>)
  else if (item && item < -3)
    return (<Table.Cell negative>{item}</Table.Cell>)
  else if (item)
    return (<Table.Cell>{item}</Table.Cell>)
  else
    return (<Table.Cell>..</Table.Cell>)
}
```

That change aside, your general approach is good in that it's both readable  and functionally correct.

Alternatively, you could revise your methods overall structure like so to minimize the total line count, and reduce four return statements down to one return statement:

```
callme = (item) => {
    return (item ? 
    <Table.Cell negative={ item < -3 } positive={ item > 3 }>{item}</Table.Cell> : 
    <Table.Cell>..</Table.Cell>)
}
```

Comment: Yes, the trick is that any property inside JSX is indeed a 'property=bool' which I've found in semantic-ui api. And your code is exactly what I was trying to figure out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize `callme` method like this:

```
callme(item) {
  if(item) {
    return <Table.Cell positive={item > 3} negative={item < -3}>{item}</Table.Cell>
  } else {
    return <Table.Cell>..</Table.Cell>
  }
}
```

Comment: While the correctly voted answer does indeed work, it's significantly more verbose than it needs to be. This answer is far more concise.